# Loading only parent image in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a blade template in laravel and it's loading very slowly. I think the main issue is the images.

So, my page is built by using a foreach loop around a group container div and this creates multiple divs on the page (anywhere between 5 and 20 depending on the order form chosen). Anyway, within this foreach loop, there is another foreach loop just for images, here:

```
  <div class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-2-10">
        <ul style="margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; float: left; width: 100%;">
            @foreach ($pgroup->image_names as $image_name)
            <li style="max-width: 220px;"><a href="http://sales.jacksonfurnind.com/imagelib/Mediums/{{ substr($image_name, 0, strpos($image_name, ',')) }}" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'my-group'}" target=_blank><img src="http://sales.jacksonfurnind.com/imagelib/Bigthumbs/{{ substr($image_name, 0, strpos($image_name, ',')) }}" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" /></a><span class="uk-text-center" style="padding: 0 0 5px;">{{ substr($image_name, strpos( $image_name, ',') + 1)  }}</span></li>

            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

I tried lazy loading them and it didn't help with loading speed/performance. However, I've thought of another solution if I can do it.

Right now, the images load as an `ul` vertically and there are anywhere from 1 to 6 images. what I'd like to do, using JS and/or CSS is keep the div/loop intact but only load the first `li` or the parent. Then when clicked, the lightbox on the image group will still contain the other images.

I'm just not sure how I would go about doing this. I want it to keep doing what it's doing but only load the parent image of the loop on the front end.

UPDATE:

I've tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
 {
     $('#imageLoop li').not(":first-child").hide();
 });
</script>

And it "works" but upon page load it shows all images, and then after a few seconds it hides the child images.
```

Comment: You may not make the interior loop. just check `if(isset($pgroup->image_names[0]))` and then print its `li` then unset the element `0` then set the remaining arry to another array `anotherArr[] = $pgroup->image_names` . At the end of the file i.e before `</body>` loop through `anotherArr[]` and print its values as javascript's array. No using jquery, you can append each image url as `<li>` to its parent `ul`

Comment: Are you able to put that in the form of an answer so I have a better idea of how to do that?

Comment: It is just guide lines and it is not suitable to be an answer. Your issue, is that the browser tries to load an render many images during main page load. The idea is to make it load less images, then it get to the end of the HTML, then it will append new images to the DOM.

Comment: It is like placing JavaScript files at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a lot of ways to do this. My solution would be to: 
1. add a key to the foreach loop. 
2. If the key is equal to 0, the first li, then print that li with the image. 3. If the key is not the first one, then print a hidden li tag and only add the link to the lightbox image.

```html
 <div class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-2-10">
        <ul style="margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; float: left; width: 100%;">
            @foreach ($pgroup->image_names as $key => $image_name)
@if ( $key == 0 )
            <li style="max-width: 220px;"><a href="Mediums/{{ substr($image_name, 0, strpos($image_name, ',')) }}" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'my-group'}" target=_blank><img src="Bigthumbs/{{ substr($image_name, 0, strpos($image_name, ',')) }}" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" /></a><span class="uk-text-center" style="padding: 0 0 5px;">{{ substr($image_name, strpos( $image_name, ',') + 1)  }}</span></li>
@else 
<li class="hidden "><a href="http://sales.jacksonfurnind.com/imagelib/Mediums/{{ substr($image_name, 0, strpos($image_name, ',')) }}" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'my-group'}" target=_blank> </a> </li>
@endif 
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

4. When the lightbox appears, you should be able to click the arrows to view all the remaining images.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks so much